# Is it possible to find the bias of connections for such a tree?

Tags: tree, nodes, edge-detection, minimum-spanning-tree, undirected-graph

Any language is fine. I'm trying to determine if this is possible.

Suppose there are N nodes that need to be connected together. There should exist a path between every pair of nodes.
x creates i connections, and y creates j connections.

The bias = |i-j|

I am trying to figure out the smallest achievable bias, given a set of possible connections from each (x and y).

**Input Format:**

Line 1: l k
There exists l nodes labeled 1 through l, and there are k connections

Next k lines: z x v
Each line indicates a connection where z and x are nodes, and c is either "x" or "y", the builder of the connection. The set of connections will always be enough to yield at least one valid set of connections.

**Here is an example of the input:**

```
4 4
1 2 x
2 3 y
3 4 x
4 1 y
```

**The output of this is** 1